# MERN stack, REST api Postman, Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, api, mern

I'm trying to create a simple REST api using Postman and the MERN stack

I have the following files

server.js, Item.js, items.js, keys.js

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const items = require('./routes/api/items');

const app = express();

// BodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// DB Config
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

//Connect to Mongo
mongoose
    .connect(db)
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));


app.use('./api/items', items);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log('server started'));
```

Item.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = Item = mongoose.model('item', ItemSchema);
```

items.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Item = require('../../models/Item');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Item.find()
        .sort({ date: -1 })
        .then(items => res.json(items))
});

module.exports = router;
```

keys.js

```
module.exports = {
    mongoURI: 'mongodb://tset:tset123@ds241012.mlab.com:41012/mern_shopping'
}
```

The server connects and connects to the DB - I get the console logs.

In postman if I try the GET and the url `http://localhost:5000` I get

```
Cannot GET /
```

If I try `http://localhost:5000/api/items` I get

```
Cannot GET /api/items
```

Comment: Change this app.use('./api/items', items); to app.use('/api/items', items);

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
app.use('./api/items', items);
```

to

```
app.use('/api/items', items);
```

Answer (score 0):

and for http://localhost:5000 , the root you have to define with

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {})
```

Comment: where should this be ?

Comment: at the beginning ,its act like your index file '/'